# models not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Using CI_Version 2.2.1 Models not connected in controller. I'm getting an error like

> Undefined property: Administrator::$administrator_model & Fatal error: Call to a member function admin_authentication() on a non-object ...

```
class Administrator extends CI_Controller {

 public function _construct()
 {
    parent::__construct();  
    $this->load->model('administrator_model');
   }

public function login_authentication()
{
  $username=$this->input->post('username');
    $password=$this->input->post('password');
  $check_login = $this->administrator_model->admin_authentication($username,$password);

}
```

Models

```
class Administrator_model extends CI_Model {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();  
}


public function admin_authentication($username,$password)
{
   $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('user_credential');
    $this->db->where('db_username',$username);
    $this->db->where('db_password',$password);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();

}
```

}

Please help to solve this issue, Thanks in advance.

Comment: add your full error message and check your file name `administrator_model.php` has correct spelling.

Comment: `$this->load->model('Administrator_model',TRUE);` try using this

Comment: `admin_authentication` in question and within your code `admin_autehentication` check your spellings carefully

Comment: post your model  with `admin_autehentication` guess it is `admin_authentication`

Comment: @ soul : try to use TRUE boolen and correct the spelling mistakes but not working

Comment: `$this->load->model('administrator_model','Administrator_model',TRUE);` add this in your controller

Comment: @Soul : added this line , but still problem not solved

Answer (score 2):

```
class Administrator_model extends CI_Model {
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();  
    $this->db = $this->load->database('default', true);
}
```

You have to load the db library first. **OR** In

autoload.php :

```
$autoload[‘libraries’] = array(‘database’);
```

Comment: `$this->load->database` loads the database library.

Answer (score 1):

is your model file in models folder root? eg: `application/models/administrator_model.php`

or it is in a sub folder eg: `application/models/admin/administrator_model.php`
then you have to load like `$this->load->model('admin/administrator_model')`

and the file name should be Ucfirst in CI3.0 but i forgot if it is necessary for CI2.2. (if you are using windows the filename wont bother until you deploy it to a linux server :)